# Cannot create new group

Tags: distributions

How can I fix this error?  I get an *unexpected error has occurred* when I try to create a new group in [Open Atrium](https://www.drupal.org/project/openatrium). I am pretty new to [Open Atrium](https://www.drupal.org/project/openatrium)
, but experienced in Drupal. Here is the syslog error message I am getting when trying to create a new group.  Any help would be appreciated.

> OgException: OG membership can not be created in entity message and bundle oa_member using the field field_oa_message_space as the field does not reference oa_group bundle in node entity type. in `OgMembership->save()` (line 62 of..... /og.membership.inc).

Comment: It seems to be an issue when I check the isgroup checkbox in the Organic groups tab.  This is also hindering updating any existing groups.  Anyone have any ideas on how to restore the group functionality?